# Android app 1.0.71 started crashing again

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Exactly when the crash occurs is not as predictable as the crashes with the prior versions, but it crashes much more frequently, often when just upvoting.

Restored 1.0.63 and it works fine.

Android 4.2.2 on Azpen A727

Comment: Coming since a lot of bugs have been fixed since then and the crash free rate is a lot higher.